# How to restrict PyPi project search by adding search terms?

Tags: python, pypi

When I enter multiple words into PyPi project search, I would expect to get results matching *all* of the search terms, like in Google Search.  But instead, it seems to return results matching *any* of the search terms.

For example, a search for `lemmatize` gives 230 results; a search for `german` gives 1526 results; but when I enter both `lemmatize` and `german`, I get 1709 results — which is apparently the union of the two result sets.  I have tried `lemmatize german`, `lemmatize AND german`, `lemmatize & german` etc., but nothing seems to work.

So my question is: How to restrict my search on PyPi to get the *intersection* of results instead of *union*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the values: [`"german" "lemmatize"`](https://pypi.org/search/?q=%22german%22+%22lemmatize%22) returns an intersection of 35 results.

This appears to be undocumented, and I've only discovered it by perusing the elasticsearch source code in warehouse, specifically the [special handling of quoted vs unquoted strings](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/blob/ff5bba2906a666a2db551ce341cba27a87a7b8ed/warehouse/search/queries.py#L71).

Related: [*Support searching for an exact phrase* #2850](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/2850)